How to listen to system event like sleep, lock, awake, shutdown, hibernate
I have a tauri application where I want to listen to the above events is there library or code that I can use, thanks

On Linux you can use ACPI. Read article on acpi and acpid on archwiki, to see how it can help you.

Here's a naive take using sys_info:
use sys_info::{PowerStatus, SystemExt};

fn main() {
    let power_status = PowerStatus::new().unwrap();
    if power_status.is_sleeping() {
        println!("Sleeping");
    } else {
        println!("Not sleeping");
    }
}

Windows-only version:
use winapi::um::winbase::GetSystemPowerStatus;
use winapi::um::winnt::SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS;

fn main() {
    let mut status = SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS::default();
    unsafe { GetSystemPowerStatus(&mut status) };
    if status.BatteryFlag & 0x80 != 0 {
        println!("Sleeping");
    } else {
        println!("Not sleeping");
    }
}

There's also a solution using PSP:
use psp::monitor::PowerMonitor;

let power_monitor = PowerMonitor::new();
  let power_event_channel = power_monitor.event_receiver();
  if let Err(msg) = power_monitor.start_listening() {
    println!("Failed to start listening to power events: {}", msg);
    return;
  }

Full example here.

Which crate are you using for sys_info::{PowerStatus, SystemExt} ?
